# issues setting up traefik with kubernetes using a simple container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, proxy, traefik

Not sure what I am missing, trying to set up a simple traefik environment with kubernetes proxying the `errm/cheese:cheddar` docker container to `cheddar.minikube`

Prerequisite:

- have minikube setup

```
git clone # personal repo that is now deleted. see solution below

# setup.sh will delete current minikube environment then recreate it
./setup.sh

# add IP to minikube
echo `minikube ip` cheddar.minikube | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: In what way are things not working? How are you testing things? Have you tried installing Traefik using their supported [helm chart](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart)?

Comment: I think the Traefik manifests in that repository are broken; there is at least a `Service` resource that appears to be absent. I think you would be better off starting with the official installation and walking through some of the examples from the documentation.

Comment: @larsks their helm charts starts a Traefik environment with preconfigured pod and the traefik docs for k8s uses k3. I wanted to understand from the basics using minikube, how traefik works with k8s. I posted the copy/paste solution below using the latest minikube and traefik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after running

```
minikube delete
minikube start

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/traefik/traefik/v2.9/docs/content/reference/dynamic-configuration/kubernetes-crd-definition-v1.yml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/traefik/traefik/v2.9/docs/content/reference/dynamic-configuration/kubernetes-crd-rbac.yml

kubectl apply -f traefik-deployment.yaml -f traefik-whoami.yaml
```

with...

`traefik-deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: traefik
  labels:
    app: traefik
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:v2.9
          args:
            - --api.insecure
            - --accesslog
            - --entrypoints.web.Address=:80
            - --entrypoints.websecure.Address=:443
            - --providers.kubernetescrd
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 8000
              # hostPort: 80
            - name: websecure
              containerPort: 4443
              # hostPort: 443
            - name: admin
              containerPort: 8080
              # hostPort: 8080
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
              - ALL
              add:
              - NET_BIND_SERVICE
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      name: admin
      port: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      name: websecure
      port: 443
  selector:
    app: traefik
```

`traefik-whoami.yaml`:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: whoami
  labels:
    app: whoami
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: whoami
          image: traefik/whoami
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: whoami
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: simpleingressroute
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: PathPrefix(`/notls`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 80
```

I was able to get a simple container working with traefik in kubernetes at:

```
echo `minikube ip`/notls
```